# My object begins to spin when collides with the wall

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection, gameobject, rigid-bodies

I have in Unity a box that is followed by a camera on a plane. I'm trying to handle the collisions between the box and different objects. When it collides with different things it spins, *jumps* and happen weird things. I uploaded to YouTube a video to show the problem. [**The video**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5iSGZDAN0t0&feature=youtu.be).

I created an *empty* that has the camera and the box. This empty has *rigidbody* of mass 1.

The empty has a script component:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Character : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        Debug.Log ("Entered OnCollisionEnter function");
        if (collision.gameObject.name == "Wall") {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = Vector3.zero;
            Debug.Log ("Inside if statement");
        }

    }
}
```

As you can see I tried to handle the collision writing a code that stops the cube of moving.

---

Additional information that could help you guys:

### The box

It has a box collider. Script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MoveCharacter : MonoBehaviour {

    public float deltaMovement = 10f;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        Moving();
    }


    void Moving()
    {
        //Moves the character to where it needs.
        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.A)) {
            transform.Translate (new Vector3 (-deltaMovement, 0f, 0f) * Time.deltaTime);
        } else if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.D)){
            transform.Translate (new Vector3 (deltaMovement, 0f, 0f) * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        float yRotation = Camera.main.transform.eulerAngles.y;
        float movementX = Mathf.Sin ((yRotation * Mathf.PI) / 180) * deltaMovement;
        float movementZ = Mathf.Cos ((yRotation * Mathf.PI) / 180) * deltaMovement;

        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.W)) {
            transform.Translate (new Vector3 (movementX, 0f, movementZ) * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
        } else if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.S)){
            transform.Translate (new Vector3 (-movementX, 0f, -movementZ) * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
        }
    }
}
```

### The wall

It is a plane with mesh collider and with or without rigidbody didn't make a difference, same problem...

---

Any help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using physics you shouldn't move an object my changing it's translation, you should move it by applying forces to the object, or at least adding a velocity to it.  This will allow the physics engine to correctly calculate the reactions with other rigid bodies.

If you move an object my adjusting it's translation then when a collision occurs it will be as though the object has materialised into the other object to the engine as it will be moving with no velocity etc, and you will get weird behaviour.

Comment: If I have `public Rigidbody rb`, and in `Start()` `rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();`, should I write in `Moving()`: `rb.velocity = new Vector3(-deltaMovement, 0, 0);`? It spins around z-axis when I wrote that in the if statement.

Comment: Have you removed or commented out all other code? I just built a quick test of what you described and my cube just glides along without issue?  I have as you say in start(), and in my Update method : if (Input.GetKey("up"))
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector3(1, 0, 0);
        }

Comment: If you do force a velocity you will also wipe out any existing velocities on your rigidbody, which you may not want to do.  Ie, when it tries to tumble/bounce/fall, if you then just set the velocity on the object you will corrupt it's current velocities and possibly ruin the effects.  Applying a force will in most cases give the best results, tweak velocities to cheat when you want specific outcomes :)

Comment: I have `if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.A)) {
   rb.velocity = new Vector3(-1, 0, 0);
  } else if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.D)){
   rb.velocity = new Vector3 (1, 0, 0);
  }`
and [**this is what happens**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-mKTEiVDQxo&feature=youtu.be) testing with keys A and D... very weird, instead of gliding.

Comment: I will accept your answer because you solved my collision problem. Thanks!

Comment: Looking at your video I suspect what you are seeing is due to friction with the surface the cube is sat on.  Just like if you have a cube of wood sat on sandpaper and pushed with your finger it would 'roll' rather than slide, if you see my meaning?  Try raising the cube up and disable gravity, so there are no external forces on it, and try again.  You could also check the friction of the materials involved also, and remove any friction and it should just glide.